# Multiple conditions for IF in Soy Template

Tags: if-statement, soy-templates

I am using SOY V2 Templates in a project and have a need to use multiple conditions in an IF statement. I have been searching for a couple of hours and haven't found anything. Essentially I want to duplicate:

`if (value !== null and value > 0)`

I have tried:

`{if $value != null & $value >0}
{if $value != null && $value >0}
{if $value != null, $value >0}
{if $value != null; $value >0}`

But all of these result in the error "not in SOY V2 Syntax". So right now I am nesting if statements and I don't think that is the best practice. Anyone know the correct way

Answer (score 2):

You're close. I think you're looking for:

```
/**
 * My template
 * @param value
 */
{template .myTemplate}
    {if $value != null and $value > 0}
      {$value} //renders the value in 'value'
    {/if}
{/template}
```

`Operators` are described [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/concepts#operators) and `if-statements` are described [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/commands#if).